# Does $\prod_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{1.127^t}\right)$ converge to a non-zero value?

Tags: infinite-product

Does the following infinite product converge to a non-zero value?

$$\prod_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{1.127^t}\right)$$

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html) gives a formula (ref 46 & 47) which, given that $1.127 > 1$, seems to imply that this is the case, but I may have misunderstood as I can't claim any knowledge of the Jacobi theta function used in (47).

Comment: Yes the given product converges to a positive value. The product you gave is related to Dedekind Eta function given by $$\eta(q) = q^{1/24}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{n})$$ which converges absolutely if $|q| < 1$. Your product is equal to $(1.127)^{1/24}\eta(1/1.127)$.

Comment: @Paramand Singh Yes, you are right, but I suspect the OP needs an  answer at a more elementary level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum_{t=1}^\infty(1.127)^{-t}$ converges (the sum of a geometric progression with ratio $<1$), and hence, by the well-known theorem, your infinite product converges. (The definition of convergence of an infinite product includes the condition that the limit is nonzero.)